Creating a reusable Angular ArrayInputComponent
I am working on creating reusable form input components using Angular's reactive forms.
For my FormArray input component, I am facing challenges.
I found I needed to use double-type casting:
get arrayGroup(): FormGroup {
  return this.formArray as AbstractControl as FormGroup;
}

Because unless I wrapped the input HTML in something like this:
<div [formGroup]="arrayGroup"></div>
I got this error:

NG01053: formGroupName must be used with a parent formGroup directive. You'll want to add a formGroup directive and pass it to an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).

My solution works and does the job, but there must be a better way.
I have shared two components, a form, and an input.
** The components **
// FILENAME: forms.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
  FormArray,
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
} from '@angular/forms';

import { ArrayInputComponent } from './array-input/array-input.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-forms',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ArrayInputComponent, CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h1>Forms</h1>
      <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <app-array-input [formArray]="formArray"></app-array-input>
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class FormsComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({});

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form.addControl('formArray', this.fb.array([]));
  }

  get formArray() {
    return this.form.get('formArray') as FormArray;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log('Form valid: ', this.form.valid);
    console.log('Form values: ', this.form.value);
  }
}

// FILENAME: ./array-input/array-input.component

import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {
  AbstractControl,
  FormArray,
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-array-input',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
    <div [formGroup]="arrayGroup">
      <h1>Array Input</h1>
      <button type="button" (click)="add()">Add</button>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of this.formArray.controls; let i = index">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
          <input full placeholder="name" formControlName="name" />
          <input placeholder="relation" formControlName="relation" />
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class ArrayInputComponent {
  @Input() formArray!: FormArray;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  add() {
    const item = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required]],
      relation: [],
    });

    this.formArray.push(item);
  }

  get arrayGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this.formArray as AbstractControl as FormGroup;
  }
}

Angular version 17

The ControlContainer DI can be used to fetch the parent FormGroup using
this.formGroup = this.controlContainer!.control as FormGroup;

Then we can use this formGroup to get the formArray.
  get formArray(): FormArray {
    return this.formGroup.get('formArray') as FormArray;
  }

After this, we configure the formArrayName and formGroup which have their own separate DIV.
 <div [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <div formArrayName="formArray">
      <h1>Array Input</h1>
      <button type="button" (click)="add()">Add</button>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of this.formArray.controls; let i = index">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
          <input full placeholder="name" formControlName="name" />
          <input placeholder="relation" formControlName="relation" />
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>

After this your component, should work fine.
Full Code:
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {
  AbstractControl,
  ControlContainer,
  FormArray,
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  FormGroupName,
  NgForm,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-array-input',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
  <div [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <div formArrayName="formArray">
      <h1>Array Input</h1>
      <button type="button" (click)="add()">Add</button>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of this.formArray.controls; let i = index">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
          <input full placeholder="name" formControlName="name" />
          <input placeholder="relation" formControlName="relation" />
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
  `,
})
export class ArrayInputComponent {
  formGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private controlContainer: ControlContainer
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.controlContainer.control);
    this.formGroup = this.controlContainer!.control as FormGroup;
  }

  add() {
    const item = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required]],
      relation: [],
    });

    this.formArray.push(item);
  }

  get formArray(): FormArray {
    return this.formGroup.get('formArray') as FormArray;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ArrayInputComponent, CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h1>Forms</h1>
      <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <app-array-input></app-array-input>
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({});

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form.addControl('formArray', this.fb.array([]));
  }

  get formArray() {
    return this.form.get('formArray') as FormArray;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log('Form valid: ', this.form.valid);
    console.log('Form values: ', this.form.value);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

If you want something even more reusable, you can give the array name as an @Input working example below
Stackblitz Demo

In Angular 17 you can use FormArray  :) (After four years, the Angular's guys solve the problem to iterate and use the variable of the loop.)

A FormArray can be a FormArray of FormsContols or a FormArray of FormsGroups
In Angular 17 (almost) you can define
formArrayOfControls!:FormArray<FormControl>
formArrayOfGroups!:FormArray<FormGroup>

Now you can iterate.
With the new @for you can use
@for (control of formArrayOfControls.controls;let i=$index;track i)
{
  //see that you use "formControl"
  <input [formControl]="control"/>
}

//and 
@for (group of formArrayOfGroups.controls;track $index)
{
  <div [formGroup]="group">
     <!--here you can use formControlName, e.g.-->
     <input formControlName="control"/>
  </div>
 }

Using the old *ngFor
<div *ngFor="let control of formArray.controls">
  <input [formControl]="control">
</div>

//and
<div *ngFor="let group of formArray.controls" [formGroup]="group">
  <input formControlName="control">
</div>

So you can be free to pass the FormArray itself to your component just use
  get formArray() {
    return this.form.get('formArray') as FormArray<FormGroup>;
  }

and pass
<app-array-input [formArray]="formArray"></app-array-input>

The Naren forked stackblitz
